# Are the Jhanas related to some of the 31 realms of existence

Tags: reference-request, jhana, realms

When I say 'related' in this sense means more about the *hue* that accompanies a jhana, this might be a very pleasant feeling, mind state or perception.

I don't know what school this question refers to. I'm just responding from some kind of intuition so any Buddhist sect is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jhanas are related to to Brahma realms

> **"There is the case where an individual, withdrawn from sensuality, withdrawn from unskillful qualities, enters & remains in the first jhana: rapture & pleasure born from withdrawal, accompanied by directed thought & evaluation. He savors that, longs for that, finds satisfaction through that. Staying there — fixed on that, dwelling there often, not falling away from that — then when he dies he reappears in conjunction with the devas of Brahma's retinue.** The devas of Brahma's retinue, monks, have a life-span of an eon. A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades. But a disciple of the Blessed One, having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, is unbound right in that state of being. This, monks, is the difference, this the distinction, this the distinguishing factor, between an educated disciple of the noble ones and an uneducated run-of-the-mill person, when there is a destination, a reappearing.
>
> "Again, there is the case where an individual, with the stilling of directed thoughts & evaluations, enters & remains in the **second jhana**: rapture & pleasure born of composure, unification of awareness free from directed thought & evaluation — internal assurance. He savors that, longs for that, finds satisfaction through that. **Staying there — fixed on that, dwelling there often, not falling away from that — then when he dies he reappears in conjunction with the Abhassara devas.** The Abhassara devas, monks, have a life-span of two eons. A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades. But a disciple of the Blessed One, having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, is unbound right in that state of being. This, monks, is the difference, this the distinction, this the distinguishing factor, between an educated disciple of the noble ones and an uneducated run-of-the-mill person, when there is a destination, a reappearing.
>
> "Again, there is the case where an individual, with the fading of rapture, he remains equanimous, mindful, & alert, and senses pleasure with the body. He enters & remains in the **third jhana**, of which the Noble Ones declare, 'Equanimous & mindful, he has a pleasant abiding.' He savors that, longs for that, finds satisfaction through that. **Staying there — fixed on that, dwelling there often, not falling away from that — then when he dies he reappears in conjunction with the Subhakinha devas.** The Subhakinha devas, monks, have a life-span of four eons. A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades. But a disciple of the Blessed One, having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, is unbound right in that state of being. This, monks, is the difference, this the distinction, this the distinguishing factor, between an educated disciple of the noble ones and an uneducated run-of-the-mill person, when there is a destination, a reappearing.
>
> "Again, there is the case where an individual, with the abandoning of pleasure & stress — as with the earlier disappearance of elation & distress — enters & remains in the **fourth jhana**: purity of equanimity & mindfulness, neither-pleasure-nor-pain. He savors that, longs for that, finds satisfaction through that. **Staying there — fixed on that, dwelling there often, not falling away from that — then when he dies he reappears in conjunction with the Vehapphala[4] devas. The Vehapphala devas, monks, have a life-span of 500 eons.** A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades. But a disciple of the Blessed One, having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, is unbound right in that state of being. This, monks, is the difference, this the distinction, this the distinguishing factor, between an educated disciple of the noble ones and an uneducated run-of-the-mill person, when there is a destination, a reappearing.
>
> AN 4.123

So as you can see, if a person dwell in the first jhana often until he dies then he will reappear in the brahma’s retinue. So I think you have to master the first jhana and dwell there very often and not lose the ability to enter it until you die. Only then you might be reborn in the Brahma retinue. If you enter the first jhana once and start killing your parents or an arahant then you probably won’t appear in the Brahma realm and will go straight to hell because you will probably lose the ability to enter jhana.

If you want to know more about the 31 planes of existence then go to this link. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html

Comment: This answer most accurately informs my insight.

Answer (score -1):

In the original teachings, the jhanas were not related to the 31 realms. In the original teachings, the jhanas were merely the Samma Samadhi of the Noble Eightfold Path.

But in what appears to be the later *Brahmanisation* of Buddhism (to convert the common Indian people to Buddhism, probably by the clergy of King Asoka) the jhanas become related to the 31 realms (similar to how Vajrayana introduced Hindu gods, such as Tara, Yellow Jumbala, Avalokiteshvara, etc, into Mahayana Buddhism).

Refer to (questionable) suttas such as [AN 4.123](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.123.than.html) and [MN 1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.001.than.html), which equate the jhanas to Brahmanistic gods.

As the Buddha predicted, relating the jhanas to Brahmanistic cosmology lead to the extinction of Buddhism in India. Because people are unable to abandon the self-survival instinct, this corruption of Buddhism continues in the 'modern' world.

The former Supreme Patriarch of Thailand described these godly realms as "ancient geography".

> *View on Heaven and Hell of Somdet Phra Nyanasamvara, Supreme Patriarch of Thai Buddhism. "As we are so familiar, in religious
>   sphere, the concept of heaven and hell is a very prominent belief. In
>   many cases, it becomes the goal of religious practice itself. On this
>   very subject, His Holiness critically analyses that the very concept
>   and belief of heaven and hell in Buddhism is a cultural influence of
>   indigenous culture and belief. He states: (I quote) ‘the subject of
>   cosmology appeared in Buddhism is clearly can be seen that it is not
>   ‘Buddhist teaching’ at all but an ancient geography. The concept and
>   belief about it was included in Buddhist Canon merely because of
>   strong influence of popular belief of the time. Later Commentaries
>   further explain about heaven and hell in a greater detail distant
>   itself from the original teaching of the Buddha. If Buddhism teaches
>   such belief on heaven and hell it would not be Buddhism at all but an
>   ancient geography. Buddha wouldn’t be the Buddha who delivered the
>   Noble Truth and ‘timeless’ message for mankind.’ (p. 1) (end of the
>   quote) He then shows in his teaching that the concept of heaven and
>   hell in Buddhism are in fact symbolic, representing the quality of
>   mind and spirituality instead. One can be in heaven and hell in this
>   very earth and life. No need to wait until one dies..."*
>
> [*Supreme Patriarch of Thailand H.H.Somdet Phra Nyanasamvara. (Head of
>   the Buddhist monks in Thailand).*](https://www.behance.net/gallery/17408307/Buddhism-images-series-of-south-Sri-Lanka)

---

> *In the course of the future there will be monks who won't listen when discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their
>   meaning, transcendent, connected with emptiness — are being recited.
>   They won't lend ear, won't set their hearts on knowing them, won't
>   regard these teachings as worth grasping or mastering. But they will
>   listen when discourses that are literary works — the works of poets,
>   elegant in sound, elegant in rhetoric, the work of outsiders, words of
>   disciples — are recited. They will lend ear and set their hearts on
>   knowing them. They will regard these teachings as worth grasping &
>   mastering.*
>
> *In this way the disappearance of the discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their meaning, transcendent, connected with
>   emptiness — will come about.*
>
> *The Buddha: Ani Sutta*